# canon advanced printing technology printer status window

Tags: printing

I need uninstall or disable canon advanced printing technology printer status window (CNAB5SWD.exe). Does anyone know how?

Comment: Maybe over the "Programs and Features"-Dialog. Open Programs and Features by clicking the Start button clicking Control Panel, clicking Programs, and then clicking Programs and Features. Than search for your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a Canon  program group that comes with an uninstall shortcut.

To simply disable it, in Windows 7 it would be:

**Start (round button) ➯ Devices and Printers**
Right-click on the **Canon** & pick **PRINTER properties** (not just *Properties*)
Go to the **Advanced** tab (approx. middle tab) and you'll see **Enable Advanced Printing Features**.  Uncheck that box.  OK etc.

[image: adv printing features checkbox]

Note that from what I've read, removing CAPT may also take away the ability to Print Preview in some programs.